# How to tune SetReadBuffer size

Tags: docker, go, networking, tcp

I am writing a service (in go) that needs to connect to client via tcp. I used Wireshark to monitor my network traffic and occasionally I see

TCP zero window size from my host machine

I wonder if setting a large size in

> func (*TCPConn) SetReadBuffer

will alleviate this. To my understanding, this function will change the operating system's receive buffer associated with the tcp connection. The client will send packets in thousands per second and typical packet data size is 1448 bytes. Also, if I run this service inside a docker image, will there be other factors that may affect the buffer size(like some docker specific limits).

Comment: Don't post screenshots.

Comment: Could it be as simple as the application is not reading data fast enough so a zero window size advertising to halt the sender from wasting packets that will be dropped?